# Дата в DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, дата, datagridview

Подскажите, можно ли как то сделать, так, что бы одна из колонок DataGridView стала приспособлена для ввода даты? Ну то есть, что бы для ячеек этой колонки, как в dateTimePicker, можно было бы выбрать число, месяц год и т.д. ?

Comment: WinForms? Прекратите насиловать труп.

Comment: Да, я всецело поддерживаю эту мысль. Но просто, конкретно, для данной задачи попросили использовать WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно сделать кастомную колонку. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7tas5c80.aspx)